# WPF View not Updated position after update Model

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, inotifypropertychanged

I have next structure:
Main window

```
<Canvas HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
    <Grid Margin="100 70 0 0">
        <local:RotateControl x:Name="rtc1" Panel.ZIndex="1" 
                             Width="{Binding ElementName=window,  Path=ActualHeight, Converter={StaticResource SizeConverter}}" 
                             Height="{Binding ElementName=window,  Path=ActualHeight, Converter={StaticResource SizeConverter}}" 
                             Radius="{Binding ElementName=window,  Path=ActualHeight, Converter={StaticResource RadiusConverter}}" 
                             Loaded="rtc1_Loaded" SizeChanged="rtc1_SizeChanged"/>
    </Grid>
    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Right" Canvas.Right="80" Orientation="Vertical">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBox x:Name="year" Width="40"></TextBox>
            <TextBox x:Name="month" Width="20"></TextBox>
            <TextBox x:Name="day" Width="20"></TextBox>
            <TextBox x:Name="hour" Width="20"></TextBox>
            <TextBox x:Name="min" Width="20"></TextBox>
            <TextBox x:Name="sec" Width="20"></TextBox>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBox x:Name="lat" Width="80" Text="55.75"></TextBox>
            <TextBox x:Name="lng" Width="80" Text="37.583333"></TextBox>
        </StackPanel>
        <ComboBox x:Name="cbHSys" Width="300" SelectedIndex="0"></ComboBox>
        <Button x:Name="GatData" Click="GatData_Click">Get data</Button>
        <ScrollViewer>
            <Label x:Name="julday"></Label>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </StackPanel>
</Canvas>
```

Custom control

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Astro" 
    xmlns:s="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">

    <local:XLineCoordConverter x:Key="XLineCoordConverter" />
    <local:YLineCoordConverter x:Key="YLineCoordConverter" />

    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Blue1Brush" Color="#e2edfa" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Blue2Brush" Color="#0080c0" />

    <Pen x:Key="BlackPen1" Thickness="1" Brush="Black"></Pen>
    <Pen x:Key="BluePen1" Thickness="0.1" Brush="{StaticResource Blue2Brush}"></Pen>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:RotateControl}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:RotateControl}">
                    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                        <Grid Background="Transparent">
                            <Line  X1="{Binding Path=Radius}" Y1="{Binding Path=Radius}" Stroke="White" StrokeThickness="1">
                                <Line.X2>
                                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource XLineCoordConverter}" ConverterParameter="1">
                                        <Binding Path="Radius"/>
                                        <Binding Path="House1"/>
                                        <Binding Path="House2"/>
                                    </MultiBinding>
                                </Line.X2>
                                <Line.Y2>
                                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource YLineCoordConverter}" ConverterParameter="1">
                                        <Binding Path="Radius"/>
                                        <Binding Path="House1"/>
                                        <Binding Path="House2"/>
                                    </MultiBinding>
                                </Line.Y2>
                            </Line>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

And model:

```
public class CircleModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = this.PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
        double _radius;
        public double Radius
        {
            get
            {
                return _radius;
            }
            set
            {
                if (_radius == value) return;
                _radius = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Radius");
            }
        }

        double _angel;
        public double Angel
        {
            get
            {
                return _angel;
            }
            set
            {
                if (_angel == value) return;
                _angel = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Angel");
            }
        }
        double _house1;
        public double House1
        {
            get
            {
                return _house1;
            }
            set
            {
                if (_house1 == value) return;
                _house1 = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("House1");
            }
        }
        ...................
    }
```

And code for change data:

```
private void GetData()
        {
            julday.Content = "";
            //SetCurDate();
            DateTime date = new DateTime(Convert.ToInt32(year.Text), Convert.ToInt32(month.Text), Convert.ToInt32(day.Text),
                                         Convert.ToInt32(hour.Text), Convert.ToInt32(min.Text), Convert.ToInt32(sec.Text));
            CalcNatalChart(date);
            _model.Radius = (this.ActualHeight - (this.ActualHeight > 150 ? 150 : 0)) / 2;
            this.ViewModel = _model;
        }

    private void GatData_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {
                GetData();
            }    

    private void rtc1_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            GetData();
            _timer = new DispatcherTimer();
            _timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0);
            _timer.Tick += timer_Tick;
            _timer.Start();
        }


        void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            julday.Content = "";
            CalcNatalChart(DateTime.Now);
            _model.Radius = (this.ActualHeight - (this.ActualHeight > 150 ? 150 : 0)) / 2;
            this.ViewModel = _model;
        }
```

All data in the form of updated correctly but View not. Only if press button GatData_Click. Dynamically change the data does not work.
Can you help me to solve it problem? Thanks

Comment: Instead of `_model.Radius` try using `ViewModel.Radius` in all places

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in these lines:

```
_model.Radius = (this.ActualHeight - (this.ActualHeight > 150 ? 150 : 0)) / 2;
this.ViewModel = _model;
```

After you reassign ViewModel, the view doesn't know about this change and uses old object instance. Either initialize ViewModel only once in constructor and then change it's properties or make that ViewModel property also observable so that you could notify when the data is changed.

Comment: I did it but it not helped me. I set init ViewModel  only in constructor:

Comment: And how did you change the Radius property? You need to use it in this manner: this.ViewModel.Radius = 12;

Comment: Thanks. All working but as I wrote below only if change the data in the form.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one...

instead of your `this.ViewModel = _model;` put `this.ViewModel.Radious = _model.Radious;`